# Powershell script to sum only specific records from file(s)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to work with a directory full of files.

I want to find specific rows within the file,
from those rows, extract a numeric value
and them sum up all these values, for all values, in a directory.

It would look like this...

```
File1.txt
bread:123
ham:456
eggs:789

File2.txt
bread:999
mayo:789
eggs:123
```

and so on...

I want to find the row with eggs, extract the number, and sum these numbers together across files.

I found this script from other posts but it's only segements, I still have trouble understanding how to use and pipe/ variables /braces.

```
dir . -filter "*.txt" -Recurse -name | foreach{(GC $_).Count} | measure-object -sum
#?
Get-Content | Select-String -Pattern "eggs*"
#?
$record -split ":"
```

I want the script to say "eggs = 912" which would be 123 + 789 = 912

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```sh
$pattern = 'eggs'

$sum = Get-ChildItem . -File -Recurse -Filter *.txt | 
       Get-Content | 
       Where-Object { $_ -match $pattern } |
       ForEach-Object { ($_ -split ':')[1] } |
       Measure-Object -Sum |
       ForEach-Object Sum

"$pattern = $sum"
```

Output:

```
eggs = 912
```

- `Get-ChildItem` finds all files recursively that match the filter
- `Get-Content` reads each line of every file and passes that on in the pipeline
- `Where-Object` includes only lines that match the given RegEx pattern
- The `ForEach-Object` line splits the line at `:` and extracts the sub string, which is at array index `[1]`.
- `Measure-Object` accumulates all numbers (it converts strings to `double`, if necessary). Internally, it creates a variable in its `begin` block, accumulates the pipeline input to this variable in its `process` block and outputs the variable value in its `end` block.
- The last `ForEach-Object` line is necessary because `Measure-Object` actually outputs an object with a `Sum` property, but we only want the value of that property, not the entire object. If you'd remove that line you'd have to write `"$pattern = $($sum.Sum)"` instead, to access the `Sum` property of the `sum` object.

Comment: THANK YOU , this is exactly correct. Everything after the get-content pipe is where i get confused. Your explanations are very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Looking closer at the code and explanations. $_ allow for a per record usage from the previous pipe i think. The middle forEach-Object is processing through the matches which were filtered by the where-object..... The ( ) is what's creating the array, and the index is being sliced with the bracket [1]... with the last 2 line, of Measure-Object and ForEach-Object, i would think these are in a narrower scope, so i'm not sure how the sum is remembered between files(?)....will have to play around but Thank you again!

Comment: @The_BMan You got that mostly correct. I've added a few explanations about `Measure-Object` and `ForEach-Object` to help you understand them better.

Comment: @The_BMan For even better understanding of how `Measure-Object` is able to do its job, I suggest to read a tutorial about how to create your own pipeline-aware function, e. g. [this one](https://powershell.one/powershell-internals/scriptblocks/support-pipeline). It even has a sample function `Count-Object` which works very similar in principle. When starting to learn PoSh, I only really grasped the concept of pipelines after creating my own pipeline function and played around with it.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, this is great. You are the person who makes the world work

Comment: @The_BMan As I just learned, `Measure-Object` automatically converts strings to numbers, so I've removed the superfluous `[int]` cast. Even if the input is `int`, the result is always `double`.

Answer (score 3):

You can treat the as csv files.  import-csv doesn't take wildcards for the filename.

```
import-csv file1.txt,file2.txt -Delimiter : -Header item,amount | 
  where item -eq eggs | measure -sum amount

Count             : 2
Average           :
Sum               : 912
Maximum           :
Minimum           :
StandardDeviation :
Property          : amount
```

Comment: Very cool. I like the multiple approaches. Thank you

Comment: Really elegant and I just learned that `Measure-Object` always converts its input to `double` for `-Sum`.

Comment: Nice; the approach relies on `Import-Csv` quietly ignoring empty lines and tolerating lines with fewer fields than implied by the header. As for the lack of wildcard support: This should be considered a _bug_, and may get fixed in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) at some point (the bug is still present as of v7.3.8): see [GitHub issue #6583](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6583).